# Is there an automated method for forcing an open/save in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

Is there an automated method for forcing an open/save on a Netsuite sales order.  This will trigger an update on the value available to ship.

Comment: Not sure how this is related to sql server?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of options to do this assuming you already have the script and logic for updating the whatever you want to update.

You can have a scheduled script that will run and simply load your order and submit it or have a user event script deployed on a transaction related to the order or items in the order.

SuiteScript 1.0

```
var record = nlapiLoadRecord('salesorder', idSo);
var idRecord = nlapiSubmitRecord(record)
```

SuiteScript 2.0

```
var objRecord = record.load({
              type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER, 
              id: idSo }); 
var recordId = objRecord.save();
```

With the codes above you can simply add your logic and you are good to go.